# Lean packet protocol for AS3 and C#?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, protocols, network-protocols

Is there by chance a lean (meaning not xml or json) packet protocol that is implemented in both actionscript 3 and C#? It would be great if there was one that already had an implementation in both languages. If not, I may have to code one side. That being said, would it be stupid/unsafe to figure out (or find documents of) C#'s serialization specification and then use that so I just have to make an AS3 to C# object encoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/OtherLanguages).

Of the C#, protobuf-net and dotnet-protobufs are pretty robust. I haven't tried the AS versions personally.

Marc

Comment: For pure .NET usage, I would normally lean towards protobuf-net (it is more like "standard" C# usage etc), but for a similar API at both ends dotnet-protobufs might be more appropriate.